# Interrupt vector addresses in ATMega2560

Tags: vector, interrupt, avr

I have a question concerning the addresses of the interrupt vectors in ATMega2560.

1. According to the data sheet, the vectors are at the program addresse $0000, $0002, $0004, ..., $0070.
2. After disassembling code of an ATMega2560 (on an Arduino Mega board) I noticed that the vector are at the addresses $0000, $0004, $0008, ..., $00E0.

I assume that (2) is correct. According to the AVR Instruction set manual a jmp instruction has a 4 Byte opcode which fits this assumption (and the assembler uses the jmp instruction to jump to the ISR).

But why does the data sheet then tell something different? Or is my understanding maybe totally wrong?

Thanks a lot for all answers and kind regards!

Comment: they use word addresses numbering in datasheet. a word is 2 bytes

Comment: Thank you. This explains the difference.